# Get number of occurences of a pair of values at same index in two different lists

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have two lists (same size)

```
a = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
b = [2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2]
```

Suppose I need to get the number of occurences of value '2' in list 'b' when the value '0' is matched in list 'a'. for instance on the two previous lists, I expect to get 4 (I have values '0' in 'a' and '2' in 'b' simultaneously at positions 0,1,3,7)

One way to do it:

```
len([x for x,y in zip(a,b) if x==0 and y==2])
```

But I was wondering if there is a better solution

Comment: You meant list, not array, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your arrays (perhaps you meant lists) are going to be longer, using [`itertools.izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) would be better, because `zip` will create a list of tuples of corresponding elements from both `a` and `b`

```
>>> a = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
>>> b = [2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2]
>>> from itertools import izip
>>> sum(x == 0 and y == 2 for x, y in izip(a, b))
4
```

Here, `x == 0 and y == 2` is a boolean expression, so the result will be either `True` or `False`. In Python, `True` is `1` and `False` is `0`.

```
>>> False == 0
True
>>> True == 1
True
```

and `sum` function sums up all of them and gives the result.

Also, note that we are not passing a list to `sum` (the `[` and `]` are not there). It means that we are passing a generator expression. `sum` will invoke the generator expression to get a value. So, a temporary list is not created, like in your `len` solution, but the values are retrieved on demand. Read more about generators and generator expressions, [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)

So, this solution will be very space effective and very useful if your lists are going to be very long (since it avoids any temporary list construction).

Answer (score 2):

If your lists aren't ridiculously large, just use list.count:

```
a = [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
b = [2, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1, 0, 2]
print(zip(a,b).count((0,2)))
```

For Python 3, where zip returns an iterator, you'll have to use list(zip(..)) to produce a list. If you want to count multiple variants, a collections.Counter can do that:

```
>>> print collections.Counter(zip(a,b))
Counter({(0, 2): 4, (1, 0): 2, (0, 1): 1, (1, 1): 1})
```

Also, knowing that Python's True and False have the numeric values 1 and 0 (in fact, bool is a subtype of int), we can simply sum the generator:

```
sum(pair==(0,2) for pair in zip(a,b))
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, style-wise this seems very pythonic and understandable, so for me it's good enough.

Performance-wise you need to iterate both so I don't think you're. The only improvement would be using izip and not building the actual list of matching elements. Something along the lines of :

```
from itertools import izip
sum(1 for x,y in izip(a,b) if x==0 and y==2)
```

could work.
In any case, improve only if it's needed performance-wise. (btw you forgot the commas between elements in your example)

Answer (score 0):

```
sum(x == 0 and y == 2 for x, y in zip(a, b))
```